# Why submit called from inside of panelCollection doesn't submit data changes from the rest of page

Tags: oracle-adf

My application is build using Oracle ADF 11gR1 (JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0), and I have a problem with data submitted by commandLink placed inside of panelCollection.
I have following page fragment structure:

```xml
<af:panelAccordion id="pa1">
  <af:showDetailItem id="sdi1">
    <af:panelFormLayout id="panelFormLayout1">
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.C11.inputValue}" id="it34" />
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.N04.inputValue}" id="it32" />
      <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.N13.inputValue}" id="soc4" autoSubmit="true" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.N13.items}" id="si4"/>
      </af:selectOneChoice>
      ...
    </af:panelFormLayout>
  <af:showDetailItem>
  ...
  <af:showDetailItem id="sdi4">
    <af:panelCollection id="pc2">
      <af:table value="#{bindings.Table.collectionModel}"
                var="row" rows="#{bindings.Table.rangeSize}"
                filterModel="#{bindings.Table.queryDescriptor}"
                queryListener="#{bindings.Table.processQuery}"
                varStatus="vs"
                selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.Table.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                selectionListener="#{bindings.Table.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                rowSelection="single" id="t2">
        <af:column id="c19">
          <af:commandLink id="cl1" textAndAccessKey="#{row.bindings.C0.attributeValue}" actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.Bean.handle}"/>
        </af:column>
        <af:column id="c17">
          <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.C1.inputValue}" id="it17" />
        </af:column>
        <af:column id="c16">
          <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.C2.inputValue}" id="it42" />
        </af:column>
        ...
      </af:table>
    </af:panelCollection>
  </af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelAccordion>
```

CommandLink (*id="cl1"*) placed in table column *c19* has defined *actionListener*. Method of this performs operation which base on data given in selected row in table and in controls from panelFormLayout above.

When commandLink is pressed, and actionListener method fired, I see (in the results and in debug) that data changes from panelFormLayout are not submitted, except the ones which has *autosubmit* set to true. But if I place the same commandLink outside of panelCollection all data are submitted.

My question is how I can force submit of data from whole pageFragment when actionListener is fired from panelCollection inside?

Autosubmit on all controls outside of panelCollection doesn't seem to be a good solution because of many uncessary POST requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is the had optimised lifecycle which is used for some components including table and panelAccordion. His means that the values are only submitted inside the boundary of the component. In your case it means that only the showDetailItem is submitted.

To submit the form to you have to set the id if the link as partial trigger to the form.

A detailed description can be found in this presentation http://de.slideshare.net/mobile/stevendavelaar/18-invaluable-lessons-about-adfjsf-interaction in lesson 17

Comment: Yes, that is is! Thanks a lot. I have to add panelCollection instead of commandLink to partialTriggers of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try putting the panel collection inside a subform?